# Extracting an element from a page using Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

[image]
I want get only order id from **href** using Cypress
any one can help me?

This is my cypress code`cy.get('[href="/practice/orders"]').click()

```
    cy.get('a[href="/practice/orders/60252307a7e132152c5ebc9b"]:nth(2)').type("a href");
    cy.get("tbody")
    .contains("a href")
    .closest("td")
    .find("td")
    .then(text => {
        const rowText = text;
```

})`

Comment: There's no "database" here, just HTML.

Comment: I don't have database i'm trying to get from website

Comment: @Krupal DO you want to get all the order id's from the table or just this one ?

Comment: just one id want to get

Comment: What seems to be an issue?

Comment: @Jonah want this, in this image [https://prnt.sc/zaoc0z]

Answer (score 0):

1.If you want to get all the order Ids from the table, you can use [each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Syntax) to loop through the table and get all order ID's, provided that the second `<td>` element contains the order id in each row.

```
cy.get('td:nth-child(2) > a').each(($ele) => {
  var orderid = $ele.text()
  cy.log(orderid)
})
```

2.If you just want the order id from one element as shown in the screenshot you can use:

```
cy.get('tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > a').invoke('text').then((text) => {
            cy.log(text) //text is the order id
        })
```

Comment: Thanks, but it showing this error : Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: a[href="/practice/orders/60252307a7e132152c5ebc9b"], but never found it.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot or copy the href element, the error indicates that the locator value is different from what is there in the screenshot. Or better can you tell me whether the element is located at the same place as shown in the screenshot ?

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you try again ?

Comment: still getting error : **Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > a, but never found it.
**

Comment: can you try again there was a `)` missing. And if it doesn't work, please send the image of the html for your element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228614/discussion-between-alapan-das-and-krupal).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue this is how I did it applied to your code.  I also had one where I wanted the element's title so just did `$element.attr('title');`

```
   cy.get('a[href="/practice/orders/60252307a7e132152c5ebc9b"]:nth(2)').type("a href");
    cy.get("tbody")
    .contains("a href")
    .closest("td")
    .find("td").should(($element) => {
       const rowText = $element.text();
     });
```

I am assuming that your locators are all getting the correct element